# Is there a Chrome bookmark extension that if you search your book marks will show you what other's have saved on the topic?

Tags: google-chrome

I am looking for a chrome extension that would be some type of Bookmark manager that shows you what others have saved on the topic when you search your bookmarks?  Has anyone seen anything like this?  I have read through the bookmark managers that come up but didn't read anything quite like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to see data on other computers, not simply through the Google Chrome Extension API at least. You could probably trade data between users of the extension with a server, but there would be no offline ability. Generally go with the rule of thumb that you cannot access data on another persons computer, without their permission.